# Variable estática no se inicializa inmediatamente en C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

```
public class variables{

    public static int edit{get;set;}


}// Fin de la clase
```

También he tratado:

```
public static int edit=0;

public static int editar{get;set;} 

public static int edits{get{return edit; }
```

Usándola en el formulario

```
form:form1{

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        variables.edit=1;

        //cambiando el valor de la variable a 1 
    }

    private void btnNewForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        form2 otroForm=new form2();
        otroForm.Show();

    } //llamando el nuevo formulario donde se usará el valor

}
```

Fin del formulario uno

```
form:form2{

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        MessageBox.show(variables.edit.ToString());

    }//mostrando el valor de la variable en un mensaje 

}// Fin del form dos
```

El MessageBox en todos los casos me devuelve 0 almenos que lo vuelva a llamar.  Necesito saber como hacer para que los valores que paso se inicialicen a la primera ya que la tengo que utilizar muchas variables que mantengan datos de un formulario a otro y las uso en el load.

Comment: Probaste con `public static class variables {}` ?
Por lo que puedo leer tu codigo no presenta ningun problema.

Answer (score 4):

Si la idea es pasar datos de un form a otro no uses variables `static`, pasa los valores en el constructor del form

[[WinForms] – Pasaje de información formulario hijo](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/01/winforms-pasaje-de-informacion.html)

La idea es definir un constructor para el `form2`

```
public class form2 : Form{

    private _editar = false;

    public form2(){
       InitializeComponente();

    }

    public form2(bool editar) : base() {
         
        _editar = editar;
    }
}
```

desde el `form1` usarias

```
public class form1 :Form{

    private void btnNewForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        form2 otroForm = new form2(true);
        otroForm.Show();

    } 

}
```

cuando instancias el `form2` podrias asignar la variable que indica si debe editarse o no

De esta forma no necesitas definir variables globales

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, como sugirio  @NaCI tenia que poner la clase estatica. Leandro Tuttini ya sabia que se podia resolver haci pero es que quiero reutilizar los formularios y de esa forma se complica mas porque tengo que utilizar varios parametros

Comment: @FrankelyHernandez justamente de esta forma es que mejor se reutiliza. Si los parametros son varioas crea una clase y pasa esta al constructor del form. No recomiendo definir variables de forma global son para problema ademas que rompe con los conceptos de encapsulado de la funcionalidad